# Are French beaches open for the public in general?

Tags: france, covid-19, beaches

Due to the current covid-19 situation many countries have limited the public places in some way. For instance, in Spain there are some beaches that have a limited number of spaces available that need to be booked in advance or not (first come first served).

What is the current situation in France? Can you use the beach as usual or you need to book or there is any limitation like that?

Comment: Any specific beach?

Comment: No @Daniil, I'm planning a roadtrip to France and I'd like to stop in several beaches (no planing)

Answer (score 3):

Most beaches should have reopened but rules could differ locally, the best way to be absolutely sure that there are no restrictions is to check for signs before going onto the beach.

The main thing to know is that whenever there were restrictions, it was usually a ban on so-called “static“ use of the beach, i.e. you could go there, swim, surf, walk or run and then go back home but sunbathing or spending the day at the beach was not allowed. I have never heard of slots or reservations on French beaches.  Right now, even “static“ acitivites should be allowed but it is still forbidden to gather in groups of more than 10 people (except for political reasons, following a court decision).

Comment: I would be curious to know why this was downvoted...

Comment: Oh @Relaxed, it seems that slots have arrived to France also: "Ce sont 252 emplacements installés sur 2 000 mètres carrés sur la plage communale de La Grande Motte. Réservables gratuitement en ligne à la mi-journée sur le site de l'office du tourisme, ces "carrés réservés" permettent de se poser sur le sable pour bronzer sans port de masque" (from the first link posted by Franck)

Answer (score 2):

Many (most I believe) French beaches are now open for the public, sometimes with restrictions. It depends on the local authorities.

Sources:

- https://www.linternaute.com/sortir/magazine/2496209-plages-ouvertes-ou-fermees-liste-par-departements-reouverture-le-2-juin/
- https://www.lci.fr/population/carte-plages-ouvertes-en-france-deconfinement-covid-19-ascension-littoral-manche-mediterranee-atlantique-quelles-sont-les-zones-accessibles-sur-les-cotes-francaises-2154343.html

  [image]

Comment: I can't set as a valid answer (altough the map is a great resource) because it seems that the map and the info is not updated. It's not updated since a month ago (may 25th).

Comment: @Ivan finding a continuously updated map for all beaches in France might be difficult :-( the main point of this answer was to indicate that it depends on the local authorities, but most should be open by now.